# Почему не работают websocket в iOS и Firefox?

Tags: ios, websocket, firefox, socket.io, feathersjs

Использую socket.io и при подключений на фронт использую такой код:

```
this._socket = io(environment.domain.api, {
      transports: ['websocket']
});
this._socket.on('reconnect_attempt', () => {
      this._socket.io.opts.transports = ['polling', 'websocket'];
});
```

На backend использую feathers.
Кто-то знает почему не работают сокеты на iOS и в Firefox?

Comment: вопрос актуальный, в safari не работают сокеты, может кто-то сталкивался

Comment: Непонятность вопроса актуальна, что значит «не работают»? К чему идёт подключение? Как настроен бэкенд? В Chrome работает? Ошибки в консоли какие-нибудь? `on('error', (error) => {console.log(error)})`?

Comment: Подключение идёт к API который написан на FeathersJS. К сожалению в консоли на телефоне не могу посмотреть.

Comment: Тогда `alert(error)`, он должен работать везде :) Ну и `window.onerror` можно слушать на всякий случай с таким же алертом

Comment: не подумал :)
спасибо, попробую